# Sending an array of json objects to action with ajax in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I hope anyone can help me (Sorry for my english).
I have a problem when I want to send un array of arrays in ajax.
My model is:

```
public class SJSonModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool isChecked { get; set; }     
}

public class SJSonModelList
{
    public List<SJSonModel> Features { get; set; }
    public List<SJSonModel> MenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

The controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckPreferences(SJSonModelList postData)
    {
        BindUserFeatures(postData.Features);

        return Json(new { status = "Success", message = "Passed" });
    }
```

The View simplified:

```
<div class="Feature borderRadius Items">
    <h2>Title
        <input type="checkbox" class="Item" name="featureName"/>
    </h2> 

   <div class="FeatureDetails subItems">                 
        <a href="@Url…">featureName</a>
        <input type="checkbox" class="subItem" name="subItemName"/>
   </div> <!-- endOf FeatureDetails -->
```

The JQuery code:

```
    var isChecked = false;
    var features = new Array();
    var menuItems = new Array();
    var postData = new Array();
```

Here I fill the features, the menuItems with the featureName/menuItemName and isChecked boolean for each feature/menuItem

```
menuItems.push({ "Name": $(this).attr('name'), "isChecked": isChecked });
features.push({ "Name": $(this).attr('name'), "isChecked": isChecked });

postData.push({ "features": features, "menuItems": menuItems });
postData = JSON.stringify(postData);
```

The ajax function:

```
    $(':submit').click(function () {

        postData.push({ "features": features, "menuItems": menuItems });
        postData = JSON.stringify(postData);

        $.ajax({
                 url: '@Url.Action("CheckPreferences")',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: postData, 
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 traditional: true,
                 success: function () { window.alert('@Resource.AjaxSuccess'); },
                 error: function (event, request, settings) {  window.alert('@Resource.AjaxError' + ' : ' + settings); },
                 timeout: 20000
        }); //endOf $.ajax
    }); //endOf :submit.click function
```

When I do  alert(postData), in client side it contains the true values for each item but in the conroller the postData.Features and postData.MenuItems are null.

I have tried to pass just one array to the controller too:

```
 features = JSON.stringify(features);
```

in $.ajax:

```
{… data: features,…}
```

in controller:

```
 ActionResult CheckPreferences(IEnumerable<SJSonModel> features)
```

and it works fine, but I don't know how to pass the array of json objects to my contoller. So I hope to retrieve the answer here :)

Thank you very much.

Comment: is there anyway you could post up the JSON Object that is actually going back to the server? could be that its not getting pushed right. try fiddler and see what the request for the ajax is

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of combining your arrays into another array, you're best of sending them as individual parameters to the action method, something like:

Assume we still have your two arrays:

```
var features = new Array();
var menuItems = new Array();
menuItems.push({ "Name": $(this).attr('name'), "isChecked": isChecked });
features.push({ "Name": $(this).attr('name'), "isChecked": isChecked });
```

Then in your JQuery ajax call do the following:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CheckPreferences")',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: "json",
        traditional: true,
        data: { 
            menuItems: JSON.stringify(menuItems),
            features: JSON.stringify(features)
        },
        success: function () { window.alert('@Resource.AjaxSuccess'); },
        error: function (event, request, settings) {  
            window.alert('@Resource.AjaxError' + ' : ' + settings); },
        timeout: 20000
});
```

Then your controller method should be:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckPreferences(string menuItems, string features)
{
    var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var deserializedMenuItems = (object[])js.DeserializeObject(menuItems);
    var deserializedFeatures = (object[])js.DeserializeObject(features);
    var myFeatures = new List<SJSonModel>();
    var myMenuItems = new List<SJSonModel>();

    if (deserializedFeatures != null)
    {
        foreach (Dictionary<string, object> newFeature in deserializedFeatures)
        {
            myFeatures.Add(new SJSonModel(newFeature));
        }
    }

    if (deserializedMenuItems != null)
    {
        foreach (Dictionary<string, object> newMenuItem in deserializedMenuItems)
        {
            myMenuItems.Add(new SJSonModel(newMenuItem));
        }
    }

    var myModelList = new SJSonModelList(myFeatures, myMenuItems);

    return Json("");
```

I also edited your classes by putting in a constructor to work with the above code, like so:

```
public class SJSonModel
{
    public SJSonModel(Dictionary<string, object> newFeature)
    {
        if (newFeature.ContainsKey("Name"))
        {
            Name = (string)newFeature["Name"];
        }
        if (newFeature.ContainsKey("isChecked"))
        {
            isChecked = bool.Parse((string)newFeature["isChecked"]);
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool isChecked { get; set; }
}

public class SJSonModelList
{
    public SJSonModelList(List<SJSonModel> features, List<SJSonModel> menuItems )
    {
        Features = features;
        MenuItems = menuItems;
    }

    public List<SJSonModel> Features { get; set; }
    public List<SJSonModel> MenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your message. I've done it yet it doesn't work, the values of menuItems and features are null

Comment: Hi @LilitMR, check my new edit of my answer. I've tested that exact code and it works fine :)

Comment: Hi , thank you so much for your message. I'll try it this monday at the office and I answer you quickly. Pass a fine WE :)

Comment: Sweet :). Could you put the tick next to my answer and mark me as the answer? :)

Comment: No problems :). Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing serialized data from the client define postData as type string in your controller and then use JavascriptSerializer.Deserialize to deserialize the JSON into your object. This way you can also catch any errors that may occur during deserialization and debug the JSON that is sent over. One thing I am not sure if is if the Deserializer expects to match field names on case sensitivity. You define your arrays in the Model as "Features" and "MenuItems" whereas in the Javascript they are defined as "features" and "menuItems".

Comment: What exactly did not work? If you debug the application can you see JSON in the string that is returned to the controller? Or does it fail on deserialization?

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your messages. I've just not used the serialization correctly, but it works fine now :)

Comment: The problem was not the serialization but the postData:  postData.push({ "features": features, "menuItems": menuItems });
postData = JSON.stringify(postData); ...$.ajax {...data: postData...}

Comment: I shoud do   data: {
                            menuItems: JSON.stringify(menuItems),
                            features: JSON.stringify(features)
                    }